# Group pandas elements according to a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Sentences':['Sentence1', 'Sentence2', 'Sentence3', 'Sentences4', 'Sentences5', 'Sentences6','Sentences7', 'Sentences8'],'Time':[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

[image]

I was wondering how to extract all the "Sentences" according to the "Time" column. I want to gather all the "sentences" from the first "1" to the last "0".

Maybe the expected output explains it better:

```
[[Sentences1,Sentences2,Sentences3],[Sentences4,Sentences5,Sentences6],[Sentences7,Sentences8]]
```

Is this somehow possible ? Sorry, I am very new to pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = df['Time'].cumsum()
df.set_index([s, df.groupby(s).cumcount()])['Sentences'].unstack().to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['Sentence1', 'Sentence2', 'Sentence3'],
 ['Sentences4', 'Sentences5', 'Sentences6'],
 ['Sentences7', 'Sentences8', nan]]
```

#### Details:

- Use `cumsum` to group by Time = 1 with following Time = 0.
- Next, use `groupby` with `cumcount` to increment within each group
- Lastly, use `set_index` and `unstack` to reshape dataframe.

Comment: Wow ! That's impressive!! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @henry Thanks!   Happy coding!